# Filter the questions of a tag by day

Tags: support, search

Can we filter the questions of a tag by date/today/yesterday?

For example: I want to filter the questions of `C` which are posted today. How can we filter those?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: As you can see from Samuel's comment, [tag:status-completed] :)

Comment: It already largely works that way.  Just click the [c] tag and you get [this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).  Just make sure the "newest" tab is selected so they are ordered by post date, everything asked "today" appears first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *created* to filter by creation dates, with relative dates:

[[c] created:1d is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+created%3A1d+is%3Aq)

Comment: or even `lastactive`